# Merge 2 columns if they match (c1 compares to partial a1)

Tags: excel

What I wanna do is merge 2 columns if they match, BUT column C should match just the text before a special character from column A.

Example:

A1: mailadress|owner

C1: mailadress

The code should create B2 like this: mailadress|owner

So C1 compares to just a part of A1, the part before the special character "|"

Note: C1 should compare to A1,A2,A3,...,An and if it doesnt find, put a message in B1.
Same for C2, etc.

nrElements A > nrElements C

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(LEFT(A1,FIND("|",A1)-1),C:C,0)),"message",A1)
```